# Mining Twitter using searchTwitter R Programing

Tags: r, twitter, social-networking, data-mining

I am trying to do a loop to using searchTwitter to search by days. I don't get an error if I hard code the dates for the since and until, however if I try to use a vector, I am encountering this error. Can anyone help explain what's the cause of the problem??

```
> time_period
[1] "2013-01-01" "2013-01-02" "2013-01-03" "2013-01-04" "2013-01-05"
> hashtag1.list <- searchTwitter(hashtag1, n=5, lang = NULL, retryOnRateLimit=100, since = time_period[i], until = time_period[i], cainfo="cacert.pem")
Error in strsplit(since, " ") : non-character argument
```

Comment: Is this suppose to be in a loop? You may want to try `time_period[[i]]` with the double brackets.

Comment: I am still getting the error with double brackets.

`> for (i in 1:num_days) {        
+   hashtag1.list <- searchTwitter(hashtag1, n=5, lang = NULL, retryOnRateLimit=100, since = time_period[[i]], until = time_period[[i]], cainfo="cacert.pem")  #error on this line
+   hashtag1.df = twListToDF(hashtag1.list)  
+   write.csv(hashtag1.df, file=file_path, row.names=FALSE) 
+   
+ }
Error in strsplit(since, " ") : non-character argument`

Comment: What is the type of the elements of `time_period`? Edit: surprisingly, they should be in a character format not a date format.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that `time_period` should not actually be in a date format. Looking at the code for `searchTwitter` reveals:

```
since_date = strsplit(since, " ")[[1]][1]
```

which is where your code is getting caught up. You can easily see that if `time_period` is not in character format, that it will produce an error.

```
> time_period <- c("2013-01-01", "2013-01-02", "2013-01-03", "2013-01-04")
> strsplit(time_period, " ")
[[1]]
[1] "2013-01-01"

[[2]]
[1] "2013-01-02"

...

> strsplit(as.Date(time_period), " ")
Error in strsplit(as.Date(time_period), " ") : non-character argument
```